# Conditional Posterior Distribution Based on Two Simultaneous Signals

Tags: probability, bayesian

I am trapped by such a problem. Assume the state variable $\theta$ is (prior) normally distributed $N(\eta, \sigma^{2}_{0})$. Now we have two independent signals about $\theta$. Signal 1 is $s_{1}=\theta+\epsilon_{1}$, in which $\epsilon_{1}$ is normally distributed $N(0,\sigma^{2}_{1})$ and $\epsilon_{1}$ is independent of $\theta$. Signal 2 is $s_{2}=\theta+\epsilon_{2}$, in which $\epsilon_{2}$ is normally distributed $N(0,\sigma^{2}_{2})$ and $\epsilon_{2}$ is independent of $\theta$ and $\epsilon_{1}$. Now

1. please calculate the posterior distribution of $\theta$ after observing these two independent signals, i.e.$f(\theta|s_{1},s_{2})$.
2. please calculate the mean and variance of $s_{2}$ given $s_{1}$ and prior distribution of $\theta$, i.e.$g(s_{2}|\theta, s_{1})$.

I have been calculating this for a week and could not find a solution to it. Guys, please help me to find a way to calculate them. Thanks very much ~

Comment: A week? What is the joint density of $(\theta,s_1,s_2)$?

Comment: there is no information on the joint density of these three variables.

Comment: Sorry? There is all the information one needs to compute the density of $(\theta,s_1,s_2)$ (well, actually, if one adds that $\epsilon_2$ is independent of $(\epsilon_1,\theta)$, not only of $\theta$).

Comment: sorry about the missing condition. yes, we have $\epsilon_{2}$ is independent with both $\theta$ and $\epsilon_{1}$.

Comment: Then what is stopping you?

Comment: I try to calculate the posterior use conditional probability, not so directly as the following answer. Yes, the following answer is right, and I get the result with the following answer.

Comment: This is not my question: since the procedure is entirely automatic, what prevented you from following it?

Comment: \begin{align}
& f(\theta|s_{1},s_{2}) \\
&=\frac{f(\theta, s_{1}, s_{2})}{f(s_{1}, s_{2})} \\
&=\frac{f(s_{1}, s_{2}|\theta) f(\theta)} {f(s_{1}, s_{2})}  \\
&=\frac{f(s_{2}|\theta, s_{1}) f(s_{1}) f(\theta)}{f(s_{2}|s_{1}) f(s_{1})} \\
&=\frac{f(s_{2}|\theta)f(\theta)} {f(s_{2}|s_{1})}
\end{align}
  
 $s_{2}|\theta $ is normally distributed as $N(\theta,\sigma^{2}_{2})$,  $s_{2}|s_{1}$ and $s_{2}=s_{1}+\epsilon_{2}-\epsilon_{1}$ is normally distributed as $N(s_{1},\sigma^{2}_{2}-\sigma^{2}_{1})$. This method is wrong, but I could not find which part is wrong.

Comment: You seem to use $f(s_1)f(\theta)$ as if $s_1$ and $\theta$ were independent. But one can be much simpler, no? Just coming back to the joint density of $(\theta,s_1,s_2)$, as I suggested in my first comment...

Comment: @Did Is what you had in mind to write the joint density as the product of conditional and marginal density? I.e. $f(\theta, s_1,s_2) =f(s_1,s_2\vert \theta)\cdot f(\theta)$, and then use the fact that $s_1,s_2$ are independent conditional on $\theta$ to simplify the joint density further. And then to answer $(1)$ just use the definition of conditional density as joint divided by  the marginal density (of $s_1, s_2$)? Or am I also making it way too complicated?

Comment: @user106860 Conditional probabilities are not even useful here since everything is built from the three independent random variables $(\theta,\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2)$.

Comment: @Did Then, and perhaps you don't want to answer this seeing as you gave it as a hint, but what do you mean by saying that there is a simpler answer (than the accepted answer) by coming back to the joint density of $(\theta, s_1,s_2)$? I believe $\theta$ is not independent of $s_1$ or $s_2$, so we cannot factor the joint into marginals? (that's why I tried factoring into conditionals).

Comment: @user106860 Let $g$, $g_1$ and $g_2$ denote the PDFs of $\theta$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ respectively, then the joint PDF $f$ of $(\theta,s_1,s_2)$ is simply $$f(t,x_1,x_2)=g(t)g_1(x_1-t)g_2(x_2-t)$$

Comment: @Did Ah, I see. I was thinking about that as the joint density of $(\theta, \epsilon_1, \epsilon_2)$. Anyway, you were a big help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a prior distribution $$\pi_0(\theta) = \phi\left(\dfrac{\theta - \eta}{\sigma_0}\right)$$ and two likelihoods proportional to $\phi\left(\dfrac{s_1 - \theta}{\sigma_1}\right)$ and $\phi\left(\dfrac{s_2 - \theta}{\sigma_2}\right)$ so you want $$\pi(\theta|s_1,s_2)=\dfrac{\phi\left(\dfrac{\theta - \eta}{\sigma_0}\right)\phi\left(\dfrac{s_1 - \theta}{\sigma_1}\right)\phi\left(\dfrac{s_2 - \theta}{\sigma_2}\right)}{\displaystyle \int_\theta\phi\left(\dfrac{\theta - \eta}{\sigma_0}\right)\phi\left(\dfrac{s_1 - \theta}{\sigma_1}\right)\phi\left(\dfrac{s_2 - \theta}{\sigma_2}\right)d\theta}.$$ I will leave you to do the calculation.

For part 2 you can do something similar to find the posterior distribution of $\theta$ given $s_1$ and so a consequential distribution for $s_2$.  Remember that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then $E[X+Y]=E[X]+E[Y]$ and $Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)$.

Comment: We know the two signals are independent. To have $f(\theta s_{1}s_{2})=f(\theta)f(s_{1})f(s_{2})$, we also need $\theta$ is independent with $s_{1}$ or $s_{2}$. But how to prove $\theta$ is independent with $s_{1}$ or $s_{2}$ ?

Comment: Obviously $\theta$ and $s_1$ are *not* independent; nor are $\theta$ and $s_2$. Otherwise the question would be pointless as you are using $s_1$ and $s_2$ to provide information about $\theta$.  But the question states that $\theta$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ *are* independent.

Comment: Yes, $theta$ should be related with $s_{1}$ or $s_{2}$ to elicit extra information from $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$. So you are using $\theta$, $s_{1}$ and $s_{2}$ are independent to get the expression in the numerator ?

Comment: I am using $\theta$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ independent